# .NET sql injection automated (not manual) testing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sql-injection, .net-4.8

I need to create automated tests that check my .NET Framework WebAPI endpoints for SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

I've read about some tools that can be used for **manual** testing for list of vulnerabilities by providing the URL - SQLMAP, BSQL hacker, etc.

My question is - is there any tool/NuGet that is designed specifically to do automation testing of endpoints for SQL Injection?

If anybody have any experience integrating manual tools like SQLMAP in tests for SQL Injection, feel free to mention how does your solution operate.

Comment: veracode testing is good, but not free.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the "Gray Hat C#" book, where you have a description for integrating SQLMAP API into an app. I will try that.